# Adding data to pdf file in C# using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a method which will convert a datatable in pdf. In pdf, I will have a table. Now what I want to do is to add some data above that table. How can I do that in C#?

My code is as follows.

```
    public void ExportToPdf(DataTable dt, string htmlFilepath)
    {

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(htmlFilepath, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.Font fontbold = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 10);
        iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 7);


        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
        PdfPRow row = null;
        float[] widths = new float[] { 4f, 4f, 4f ,4f ,4f ,4f};
        table.SetWidths(widths);
        table.WidthPercentage = 100;
        int iCol = 0;
        string colname = "";
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Products"));
        cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {

            table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, fontbold));
        }

        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[4].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[5].ToString(), font5));

            }
        } document.Add(table);

        document.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Paragraph" for adding data like following

```
Chunk ch= new Chunk("Here is your data");
Phrase ph = new Phrase(beginning);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Add(ph);
document.Add(p);//this line must be added before you add table to document.
```

Now Note that as i mention above. paragraph object must added to document before you add table as you want this data above the table.